# Travis CI ignoring .travis.yml in PHP project, only building master branch

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, travis-ci

I have a very simple [`.travis.yml` configuration file](https://github.com/naoisegolden/Aixada/blob/61aaa8ac178e6e1b6d16a772305bd709cdf86f78/.travis.yml) in a branch named '3.0':

```
language: php

php:
 - 5.3
 - 5.4

branches:
  only:
   - 3.0

before_script:
 - composer install --dev
```

for a [Silex project with PHPUnit tests and Composer](https://github.com/naoisegolden/Aixada/tree/3.0). [This commit to branch 3.0](https://github.com/naoisegolden/Aixada/commit/61aaa8ac178e6e1b6d16a772305bd709cdf86f78) triggered [this build in Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/naoisegolden/Aixada/builds/4339277) that ignores the configuration file and is trying to build the master branch instead, that doesn't have a `.travis.yml` file, thus failing the build because it tries to run it as a Ruby on Rails project.

Why is Travis CI ignoring my `.travis.yml` configuration file?

Comment: I have a similar problem: Travis CI ignores changes to my master branch if I only change .travis.yml (which *is* on the master branch...). I had to push a fake commit to trigger a new build with new .travis.yml contents... (https://travis-ci.org/marcolino/paypalButton)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs of Travis](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Specify-branches-to-build):

> Please note that currently (for historical reasons), .travis.yml needs to be present on all active branches of your project.

So this means, you actually have to have a `.travis.yml` on your master branch, even if you don't use it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can now go into the [repository settings](http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-03-05-repository-settings/) and toggle the setting to only build commits with a .travis.yml file, which means that any branches without a .travis.yml file will be ignored.